# Let Eclipse warn me when SVN updates are available

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm working on a project with infrequent updates. Is there a way Eclipse (pref. Subclipse) can warn me when I launch it that I probably should do an update first?

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Synchronize view can accomplish this task.  First ask it to Synchronize all SVN projects in your workspace, then set it to refresh on a schedule, such as every hour.  The view will them show you all incoming changes and allow you to examine them, update etc.